# Project Euler 3 (performance)

Tags: c++, performance

This is my solution to [Problem 3](http://projecteuler.net/problem=3) from Project Euler. Is there any way how to make the solution more efficient?

```
int largestPrimeFactor(unsigned _int64 x) 
{
   unsigned __int64 remainder = x;
   int max_prime;

   for (int i = 2; i <= remainder; i++)
   {
       while(remainder%i==0) {
           remainder /= i;
           max_prime = i;
       }
   }
    return max_prime;
}
```

**Update:** Thank you all for the proposals. Based on them I modified the algorithm as follows:

1) Skip even candidate divisors.

```
while(remainder%2==0) {
    max_prime  = 2;
    remainder /= 2;     
}

for (int i = 3; i <= remainder; i += 2)
{
    while(remainder%i==0) {
        max_prime  = i;
        remainder /= i;         
    }
}
```

2) Work up to square root of remainder.

```
for (int i = 2; i*i <= remainder; i++)
{
    while(remainder%i==0) {
        max_prime  = i;
        remainder /= i;
        cout << i << " " << remainder << endl;
    }
}
if (remainder > 1) max_prime = remainder;
```

3) Generate prime numbers in advance using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm. Probably not worth in this simple example.

Comment: Efficient in which way? Lines of code? Execution time? Memory consumption? Programmer effort?

Comment: The number is odd, so you can skip even candidate divisors.

Comment: You also only need to work your way up to the square root of x. 
Pedantic: "Reminder" is a note that you write down to remember something (or what the company sends out when you haven't paid a bill), "Remainder" is what you get left over when something has been taken away.

Comment: @Bill - You can safely assume "execution time" 99% of the time, especially as the post is labeled [performance]. I would say the question is pretty clear in what it's asking.

Comment: I agree, the code has been modified.

Comment: (2) is the most important, it gives you a complexity improvement, worth thousands-fold speedup potentially (well, here it's about ~ 5x). you can then add (1) into it, but that's just 2x speedup. (3) you don't need here at all , you're right.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach:

Step 1: Generate prime numbers up to ceil(sqrt(number)) using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm.
Step 2: Use these to factor the number.

Comment: Just curious, why `sqrt( number )`. What if, for example, the number itself is a prime?.. I mean, if the given number is `7`, the largest prime factor is itself `7`... Am I missing something?

Comment: That will be much slower than the current approach. It could be competitive if the number was prime, or the product of two primes close to the square root, but generally, a sieve would only gain something if you want to factor many numbers.

Comment: @PetrBudnik - Good point, I was thinking about finding primes, not factoring.

Comment: @DanielFischer It's normal to compute the primes once and store them in a file (or in an array in a source file).  You would not Sieve every execution.

Comment: The number in the Project Euler problem is about 6*10^11. There are 23038900221 primes smaller than that number. That's one massive file or array, takes some time to read. Trial division does it in a few milliseconds. You need only a few handful of small primes, though, so if you load those in an array, yes, that could speed it up a little.

Comment: @PetrBudnik If you divide to by all numbers up to sqrt(number) and the residue is not 1, then the residue is prime.

Comment: @brianbeuning I'm not sure why we need **residue** to be a prime?.. The problem with the original answer, in my opinion, was that division was performed **only** over the _prime numbers_ up to `sqrt( x )`. The right way to do it, I think, is to divide over **each** number up to `sqrt( x )`, and in case there is no residue, check if the result is a prime (that includes checking the actual number when divisor is `1`) or the current divisor is a prime itself... I'm just trying to figure out how to check quickly if a number is a prime...

Comment: @PetrBudnik If you remove all factors less than the sqrt(x) then whatever is left is either 1 or a prime.

Comment: @brianbeuning I think, your use of word **residue** confused me. I understood residue in its mathematical sense - remainder of division.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my take on it. Hope it might be of use (EDIT: not to provoke "don't use leading underscore" comments - added a namespace). 
EDIT #2: Added a faster function `get_factor_prime_faster()` with a helper function. See notes about the speed tests in the end.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

namespace so
{
// Head-on approach: get_factor_prime()
std::uint64_t get_factor_prime( std::uint64_t _number )
{
 for( std::uint64_t i_ = 2; i_ * i_ <= _number; ++i_ ) 
  if( _number % i_ == 0 )
   return ( get_factor_prime( _number / i_ ) );

 return ( _number );
}

// Slightly improved approach: get_factor_prime_faster() and detail::get_factor_prime_odd()
namespace detail
{
std::uint64_t get_factor_prime_odd( std::uint64_t _number )
{
 for( std::uint64_t i_ = 3; i_ * i_ <= _number; i_ += 2 )
  if( _number % i_ == 0 )
   return ( get_factor_prime_odd( _number / i_ ) );

 return ( _number );
}
} // namespace so::detail 

std::uint64_t get_factor_prime_faster( std::uint64_t _number )
{
 while( _number % 2 == 0 )
  _number /= 2;

 return ( detail::get_factor_prime_odd( _number ) );
}
} // namespace so

int main()
{
 std::cout << so::get_factor_prime( 600851475143 ) << std::endl;
 std::cout << so::get_factor_prime( 13195 ) << std::endl;
 std::cout << so::get_factor_prime( 101 ) << std::endl;

 std::cout << so::get_factor_prime_faster( 600851475143 ) << std::endl;
 std::cout << so::get_factor_prime_faster( 13195 ) << std::endl;
 std::cout << so::get_factor_prime_faster( 101 ) << std::endl;

 return( 0 );
}
```

Program output:

```
6857
29
101
6857
29
101
```

Admittedly, I still cannot figure out how to check easily if a number is a prime...

EDIT: Tested in a loop for `600851475143 * 1024` number, GCC 4.7.2 with -O3, Linux, Intel i5 Core. Times are as follows (approximately):

`get_factor_prime` is `3` times faster than OP's solution;

`get_factor_prime_faster` is `6` times faster than OP's solution.