# Project Euler #3: Solved in R but "run out of application memory"

Tags: r

I'm new to learning R, and currently working through Project Euler. It seems I've solved one of the problems, but I get an error telling me I've run out of application memory (which forces me to quit) prior to finishing the computation. In turn, I'd like to ask about my options.

The problem asks:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13, and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

The first thing I did was spend some time figuring out the code to find the solution for 13195:

```
library(matlab)

> x <- 1:13195

> primes <- x[isprime(x) == TRUE]

> div_primes <- primes[13195 %% primes == 0]

> max(div_primes)
[1] 29
```

Since I was successful I thought I could then scale things up for 600851475143. However, I don't have enough application memory to finish the computation:

```
library(matlab)

> x <- 1:600851475143

> primes <- x[isprime(x) == TRUE]

> div_primes <- primes[600851475143 %% primes == 0]

> max(div_primes)
[1] 29
```

I read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245976/project-euler-3-performance) and they're using an algorithm called [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Would figuring out how to implement this be fundamentally different than using the `isprimes()` function in the matlab library?

If not, are there any other suggestions to make this workable?

Comment: One way to save memory is to only do the bottom half of the divisions, then you only need to have x range over 1:sqrt(600851475143);

Comment: Project Euler is all about figuring out how to reduce the search space. Tricks like the one @NealFultz mentions will help you greatly as you work through Project Euler.

Comment: The fundamental difference between you building your own Sieve and using `isprimes()` is the **author**. If you're using Project Euler as a way to learn R, I'd recommend writing your own sieve. You'll end up using it a lot, and I bet if you keep on doing problems you will tweak and improve your function and learn a lot out of the process.

Comment: @Gregor, I think that's good advice and I'll take it for subsequent problems.

Comment: @NealFultz, This worked perfectly, and I spent some time working on the math behind why it's the case. Very neat approach to solving this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of `isprime()` shows that it is just a wrapper for `primes()` which according to its documentation uses a variant of "Sieve of Eratosthenes" algorithm:

```
p <- seq(1, n, by = 2)
p[1] <- 2
q <- length(p)
if (n >= 9) {
    for (k in seq(3, sqrt(n), by = 2)) {
        if (p[(k + 1)/2] != 0) {
            p[seq((k * k + 1)/2, q, by = k)] <- 0
        }
    }
}
p[p > 0]
```